# Score recognition from a scoreBox by Opencv & tesseract-ocr

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

I'm working on a project with openCV for real time goal detection from a video stream by OpenCV.
So i have first to detect & extract the scoreBox, then try to read (recognize) the score by tesseract-ocr. 
My issue is when i proceed to read the score box by `tesseract`, it doesn't give me the correct result (score value)

Example: applying `tesseract` on this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z5xDWlQusAWVZDMXVTNFRrQU0/edit?usp=sharing), it gives me the result **5: 55:35  L ‘**.

Any help, what I have to do? Should I train `tesseract` or write my own OCR code ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to rewrite an OCR, but it really looks like the trained package you are using may not be adequate for this application. It might be necessary to create new [trained data](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3), as you suggested, with the appropriate font.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. After trying several things, I found that the problem is in the background. `tesseract` work very well with one color background, once we have multiple color on the same background, reuslt is completely wrong. Do you have any suggestion ?!

Comment: Quite possible, you might want to threshold the image prior to run Tesseract, or you can try a stretch of the histogram to darken the grey areas even more.

Comment: I already tried threshold but with a score box like the one in my question it doesn't give a good result (especially with the white color on the middle).

Comment: From what you are saying, Tesseract does not behave correctly with a change of background color. You could split the area in sections based on the back color, and either negate some sections, or run Tesseract separately in each sections.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Vince.Seems like it's a very good idea to split image into sections based on background, do you have any suggestion to how i can implement this (not code, only methods that i can use to do that)

Comment: If the areas are not fixed, which would be the ideal case, I'd suggest a horizontally moving window to detect the median color, or top-bottom pixels. Sorry, I don't have any other function to do it other than the calcHist() from openCV, so you may not get real time detection anymore...

Comment: @Aboullaite super old question but still relevant, hope you found out it was probably not necessary to do a lot of new/low level work.  it’s usually only minor amounts of image prep or splitting and standard libraries should work, with font variance being the only significant variable.